# install mautic on virtualmin

Tags: digital-ocean, virtualmin, mautic

I have followed this [guide](https://blog.h-educate.com/how-to-install-mautic/) to install mautic on virtual server on virtualmin. In apache config file, I have changed documentRoot to `/home/mautic/public_html/mautic`(mautic:virtual servername) and Directory to `/home/mautic/public_html/mautic/` from the default path `/var/www/html/mautic` shown in the guide. But when I test mautic on mautic.DOMAIN_NAME.com, I get 403 error `Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource. Can you install mautic on virtual and how?

Answer (score 0):

We recently added *Mautic* to Virtualmin Pro scripts installer. It will be available starting with Virtualmin 6.13.

Answer (score 0):

you have installed mautic on a subdirectory on subdomain,

/home/mautic/public_html/mautic/ will point to DOMAIN_NAME.com/mautic

you have to create a virtual sub server on your access domain mautic.DOMAIN_NAME.com. please google it, it's very easy.

if you are getting errors on DOMAIN_NAME.com/mautic. please paste last few errors from error logs in the comments.